# retrieve data from sqlite to perform edit/delete by clicking an item in custom listview with 3 fields/columns

Tags: android, listview

sir, can you help me on how i can display the details from a sqlite by clicking its corresponding custom listview item? my listview contains three columns so i wanted it to be displayed in another activity where i can edit the information and delete, etc.. at first, i thought of using row id but gave up on the idea because if i tried to delete an item in database, i cannot use the deleted row id. so the row ids of listview and database won't match. for ex. row ids from database 1,2,3... if i deleted row 2, if i add another item, it will just add to row 4... like this row 1,3,4. thanks for help in advance

```
public class CustomListView extends Activity {
final Context context = this;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    GroupDb info = new GroupDb(this);
    info.open();
    ArrayList<Contact> searchResults = info.getView();


    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.srListView);
    lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults));
    info.close();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

here is my custombaseadapter

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static ArrayList<Contact> searchArrayList;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> results) {
    searchArrayList = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return searchArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return searchArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);

        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());

    holder.txtPhone.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getPhoneNumber());

    holder.status.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getStatus());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtPhone;
    TextView status;
}
}
```

here is how i saved the database values with three fields/columns from GroupDb.class in my customlistview

```
public ArrayList<Contact> getView() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Contact> results = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_NAME, KEY_NUMBER, KEY_STATUS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String sName = "";
    String nName = "";
    String status = "";
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iNumber = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NUMBER);
    int iStatus = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STATUS);
    Contact contact;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
        contact = new Contact();
        sName += c.getString(iName);
        nName += c.getString(iNumber);
        status += c.getString(iStatus);
        contact.setName(sName);
        contact.setPhoneNumber(nName);
        contact.setStatus(status);
        results.add(contact);
        sName = "";
        nName = "";
        status = "";
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: using the `id` is the most pragmatic approach, and i'd suggest you find ways to make it work. if you `extend CursorAdapter` instead of BaseAdapter, then you can simply refresh the listview when something is deleted or changed. if you keep it the way you have it (which i don't suggest) you can simply delete or change something off your arrayLists then refresh the listView. unless, you don't want the listView to reflect changes in your database...

Comment: moreover i don't understand how you expect to do any deleting *at all*, if you don't want your row id's misordered. if it's that much of a deal, you could make a method to loop through your db and set the row id's correct when you're done. but i don't see the point, it's only use is to be a unique identifier for each row.

Comment: thanks, i'll try cursoradapter. but still, it didn't solve my problem. i still have no idea on how to use the id. i'm researching for 3 days and still no solution.

Comment: if you use a `CursorAdapter`, then `long arg3` on `OnItemClick` will actually mean something. namely the `id` of the selected row. you can query the db for just that row then do as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are maintaining arraylist of contacts. On click of list view get the position fetch contact object from that given position from your arraylist. You must have to save primary key column in your COntact Class.

Comment: finally, i get it. i've retrieved the data from my contact class. thanks